# Do you think it's a good idea to force Google AMP on all Magento pages?

Tags: magento-2.1

I have Magento 2, and I'm using an AMP extension. And there is an option that says, force AMP on all mobile pages. Should I enable this or just not enable it? What are the benefits of forcing people to use AMP if they don't have to?

The site obviously looks better on mobile without the AMP pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have decided NOT to "force AMP on all mobile pages" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

At this development stage of AMP, I think you'd better not force AMP on all mobile pages yet. As AMP is still limited at the actions which users can do on ecommerce page. For example, add to cart and checkout are still unavailable. I found a quite good blog writing about the pros and cons of AMP on Magento 2. You can check it out

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/google-amp-for-magento-pros-and-cons/